# Unify checkbox for all browser CSS Styling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I need some help to create unify checkbox in across all the browsers.
my application is using a theme which make the checkbox look ugly.

where can I globally set browser properties so checkbox will appear same across diff platforms
http://jsfiddle.net/khan777/LnL7b/109/

### CSS

```
.mycheckbox:checked {
    background: url(icon.png)no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Here's how ugly it looks in Chrome

[image: chrome checkbox]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of your problem. I am not able to see your problem in the provided fiddle, using the latest version of Chrome. As a side note, the code you posted in the question contains an error which makes it invald. Your CSS contains an error which makes it invalid. There should be a space between `.png)` and `no-repeat`. Does this fix your problem?

Comment: A screenshot showing IE and the differences between browsers would be handy too. Also, your screenshot looks nothing like the fiddle in Chrome; more checkboxes, more other elements and styles, and it may confuse people that its shows a zoomed state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you're referring to is "ugly" is the transparent background color once the box is checked, add the background color to your property in front of the URL:

```
.MyCheckBox:checked {
    display : inline-block;
    background: #fff url(http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/roblox/images/5/57/Very-Basic-Checkmark-icon.png/revision/latest?cb=20131125154354) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

If you meant something else, please add details.

Comment: Thank you Knighter, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @King Glad I could help. Can you mark this as the correct answer so your question shows as answered? Thanks.

Comment: My question get marked -2 negative even though it's common issues developer face these days., It also include CSS/HTML code via JSFiddle which anyone can use if they have the same situation. I wondered how q&a works here and how to remove the negative -2.